# calculating the path of directory relative to another path with the calculated path being in absolute form

Tags: bash

I have this directory structure for an application: bin, config, lib.

In bin directory I have a bash script. I want to be able to set variables in the bash script for config and lib directories based on the location of the script file in the bin directory. I can get the directory name for script that is executing by doing:

BIN_DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

My question is: How can I calculate the diectory paths for config and lib directories based on BIN_DIR ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably just use this:

```
cd `dirname $0`/..
BASE_DIR=`pwd`
cd -
BIN_DIR=${BASE_DIR}/bin
CONFIG_DIR=${BASE_DIR}/config
LIB_DIR=${BASE_DIR}/lib
```

Comment: this does not give the absolute path. it gives something like /../config

Comment: Hm, in your question you didn't mention, that you are looking for absolute paths.

Comment: You actually said 'relative to another path' in the title. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. I just echoed the results of this and it looks like it is giving me what I need. I will incorporate this into my original script to set Java class path.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `BIN_DIR` then you get the absolute path for your project directory with:

```
PROJECT_DIR=`readlink -f $BIN_DIR/..`
```

and then

```
CONFIG_DIR=$PROJECT_DIR/config
LIB_DIR=$PROJECT_DIR/lib
```